# vertex connectivity proof

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I was going through a graph theory book and found this

Let $G$ be a simple undirected graph. $\kappa(G) <\frac{n}{2}$ . If $G$ is connected, then $G$ must contain a simple path of length at least $2\kappa(G)$

Where $\kappa(G)$ is defined to be $G$'s [vertex-connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph).
and I wasn't able to prove this formally  .

Comment: What is $K(G)$?

Comment: vertex connectivity of graph

Comment: simple path this

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: and what do you mean by your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that all the simple paths are of length $<2K(G)<n$. Let $P$ be the longest path in the graph, then the ends of $P$ (say $a$ and $b$) doesn't have any neighbors outside $P$, and since $l(P)\le n-1$ then there is a vertex $v$ such that $v\not\in P$.

Also $d(v)\ge K(G)$ and all the neighbors of $v$ are in $P$ (but not $a$ and not $b$). So the neighbors of $v$ in $P$ are more than half the number of vertices in $P$ (i.e. $d(v)>\frac{v(P)}{2}$).

So you can find $2$ consecutive vertices in $P$ that are neighbors to $v$, and thus you can find a path larger than $P$, a contradiction.